# Spacy NLP Library issue with dependency parse

Tags: python, pycharm, spacy

**OS** : **Ubuntu**

**IDE** : **PyCharm**

Followed instruction from the official website

> > pip install -U spacy
> >
> > python -m spacy.en.download all

**Code Snippet Below:**

```
doc2 = nlp(u"this is spacy sentence tokenize test. this is second sent! is this the third sent? final test.")

for sent in doc2.sents:
    print (sent)
```

Still I am getting the error.

[image]

[image]

**After Re-Installing**

[image]

And then I install the package which is quite large actually.I did it twice already.

Is it an issue with **PyCharm**? IDE is Awesome, not going back though!

Comment: Did the download process finalize correctly? It looks like the download command failed to execute. Try running it once more `python -m spacy.en.download all` and see the logs.

Comment: Hi I'hv done that, edited screenshot attached

Comment: The problem might be in the fact that spacy loads 2 files: the vocab and the second I don't remember what, but each is >600MB in size. And, if the vocab downloads correctly, but the second one fails, you might run in errors. It happened with me before. Try running it once again with the `--force` flag and see what happens.

Comment: I have added the screenshot, I think it is a problem with python version, it is downloaded in 2.7 and I am using 3.x, Ok Needs to download in python 3.x directories

Comment: Well, if you write python3 code, then of course you need to download it for python3. Try running `python3 -m spacy.en.download all`, although I would recommend you use a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Below Code Solved the issue**

```
sudo python3 -m spacy.en.download all
```